# Why should fork() have been designed to return a file descriptor?

Tags: signals, file-descriptors, fork

On his [web page about](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) the *self-pipe trick*, Dan Bernstein explains a race condition with `select()` and signals, offers a workaround and concludes that

> Of course, the Right Thing would be to have `fork()` return a file descriptor, not a process ID.

What does he mean by this -- is it something about being able to `select()` on child processes to handle their state changes instead of having to use a signal handler to get notified of those state changes?

Comment: Does that article get input and output mixed up, or am I not reading it correct?

Comment: You can ask for signals to be delivered over pipes. That is what I do.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, yeah, he seems to use "pipe input/output" a bit oddly, but I think it's clear where he's writing and where reading from a pipe. That text is from 2003, and I'm not sure `signalfd`s and such were a thing back then?

Comment: Dan knows what he's talking about, although he can be a bit deliberately provocative.  If I were being deliberately provocative, I'd opine that Of course, the Right Thing would be to get rid of SIGCHLD.

Comment: @SteveSummit what's the problem with SIGCHLD? It's ignored by default. It won't interrupt select() or another system call unless a handler is set for it.

Comment: @mosvy I'm exaggerating slightly, but every program and every programmer I've ever seen who has tried to use SIGCHLD has had problems with it.  It's a race condition waiting to happen.  Back when all we had was blocking `wait()`, there were things you couldn't do, so someone invented SIGCHLD, but it was a bad job.  In my experience, and now that they exist, sprinkling nice, nonblocking `wait3()`,  `wait4()`, and/or `waitpid()` calls at key places (perhaps your main event loop) is a vastly superior alternative.

Comment: @SteveSummit I guess I'm not a programmer then. Consider a program that listens on a socket, accepts connections and forks children to handle them. How could it know when to reap the children if there were no way to be notified asynchronously of their termination? Wake every tenth of second even if there's no work to handle, preventing the system from going to sleep? Leave zombies hanging around and only reap them when there's something else to do? If you don't care about children and their status, there's `SA_NOCLDWAIT` and double-forking. If you do care, `SIGCHLD` is fine.

Comment: *Of course, the Right Thing would be to have `fork()` return a file descriptor, not a process ID.*  That completely ignores the fact that when the `fork()` call was created, file descriptors were a scarce resource.  Often only 8 bits were available for file descriptors.  That even [still exists in 32-bit Solaris 11 processes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29043/extendedfile-5.html#scrolltoc) for backwards-compatibility reasons. (Writing code dependent on internal implementation details is a long-term evil.  Note that the 64-bit Solaris `FILE` structure is opaque...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is described there in your source, `select()` should be interrupted by signals like `SIGCHLD`, but in some cases it doesn't work that well. So the workaround is to have signal write to a pipe, which is then watched by `select()`. Watching file descriptors is what `select()` is for, so that works around the problem.

The workaround essentially turns the signal event into a file descriptor event. If `fork()` just returned an fd in the first place, the workaround would not be required, as that fd could then presumably be used directly with `select()`.

So yes, your description in the last paragraph seems right to me.

---

Another reason that an fd (or some other kind of a kernel handle) would be better than a plain process id number, is that PIDs can get reused after the process dies. That can be a problem in some cases when sending signals to processes, it might not be possible to know for sure that the process is the one you think it is, and not another one reusing the same PID. (Though I think this shouldn't be a problem when sending signals to a child process, since the parent has to run `wait()` on the child for its PID to be released.)

Comment: That said, I don't recall exactly the cases I've read about PID reuse being a problem, so if anyone wants to elaborate or clarify on that, or even [edit] the above, do feel free to do so.

Comment: As you already stated, there's no excuse for a parent finding its own child pid has been reused. It is in full control of that situation because it is the one who calls `wait()`.

Comment: These are called [_zombie processes_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process): "a process that has completed execution but still has an entry in the process table: it is a process in the "Terminated state". This occurs for child processes, where the entry is still needed to allow the parent process to read its child's exit status"

Comment: PID and FD are both numbers that represent a kernel object, really the most important difference between PID and regular file descriptor is that the process table is global to the system, while regular file descriptor is local to the process. Having fork() returns a global handle rather than a local handle is conceptually more correct because, unlike a file handle, a child process have a life of its own that is separate from the parent. An FD always get cleaned up when the owning process dies, but a child process can live on.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that now Linux _can_ return a file descriptor (pidfd) from `clone`, which is the actual system call that fork invokes on LInux. The flag to enable this is called `CLONE_PIDFD` - See for example https://lwn.net/Articles/784831/.

Comment: @LieRyan, well, they're not really the same. fd's are indexes to a local table indeed, but exactly that allows the kernel to know which processes are holding a particular handle open. (or at least to have a reference count which is enough for preventing reuse issues.) The real meaning of an fd is in the table held by the kernel and a userspace process can't just make them up. On the other hand, PIDs are just plain numbers, and there's no way to know if some process is holding the PID of another process and is going to start firing signals.

Comment: @ilkkachu: The parent process do know that a PID won't be reused by another process until are `wait`-ed. This effectively locks the pid of the child process and is a special privilege of the parent process that other processes don't.

Comment: @LieRyan, yes, one of the parent process. But it doesn't generalize to other processes that might have gained the PID from somewhere. FDs, on the other hand, can be inherited (or passed through Unix sockets), and the inherited copies keep the file itself open just like the original where that matters.

Comment: @LieRyan even in the parent process, how many people would consider `pid = waitpid(-1, &s, 0)` unsafe? though it really is -- there's no guarantee that the `pid` wasn't already reused by the time you got your hands on it.

Comment: @mosvy, though I wonder, what's the case where that matters? If the child has exited, the parent isn't likely to send signals to it, and if the returned PID is only used to identify the child from those the parent has started, the reuse shouldn't matter (the parent should know it hasn't started a new child in the meanwhile). Then again, I suppose the waiting parent could have multiple threads dealing with child processes, which could mess this up, maybe?

Comment: @mosvy Re "*though it really is [unsafe]*", That's not true. The process sticks around (as a zombie) until waitpid reaps it. Since the process still exists, no other process can have its pid.

Comment: @Lie Ryan, Re "*Having fork() returns a global handle rather than a local handle is conceptually more correct because*", Windows uses process handles. The pid and exit code stick around until all the handles to the process are closed (rather than waiting for parent to reap), avoiding race conditions common in unix systems. When the handles keep the process alive, it makes far more sense fo them to be local handles rather than global ones.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, it's true. The PID could've been already re-cycled in the time interval between the child being reaped and its PID being returned by waitpid() and it being used in one way or another. This means that waitpid(pid) can return the pid of another, unrelated, running process. That may not matter in simple apps which only care if the return value of waitpid() is > 0 but it's something that should be kept in mind.

Comment: @mosvy, Re "*The PID could've been already reused in the time interval between the child being reaped and its PID being returned by waitpid()*", oh, that's what you meant? Sure, but so what. The PID would only be checked against processes you've previously launched. So unless the process launched another process since it called `waitpid`, it doesn't matter. Yeah, you'd need a lock in a multi-threaded app, but that's no surprise.

Comment: @mosvy Re "This means that waitpid(pid) can return the pid of another, unrelated, running process." This simply is not true. waitpid() will only ever return information about children of the caller. If one call to waitpid() reaps a certain child PID and that PID is recycled for another (unrelated) process [i.e., the child of another process], then a second waitpid() in the parent will not tell you about termination of the unrelated process that happens to have reused the PID.

Comment: @mtk it's perfectly true, please re-read my comment. It's about a race -- stuff may happen in the time between the child was reaped, its pid was returned to the userland program, and its pid was used in any way. That "stuff" may be the pid being recycled. It's not about a kernel becoming confused and deciding to return an unrelated pid. See also my answer and how `waitid(WNOWAIT)` may help with that.

Comment: @mtk, well I suppose it can, in the sense that if program A starts a child B and gets PID 123 for it, then if `waitpid()` returns telling PID 123 exited, then looking at PID 123 _at that moment of time_, it might be some completely unrelated process X. But I still do wonder when that would matter, because A just needs to save the PID when launching B, and it can then compare the returned PID to that to know it was child B that returned. Whoever's using the same PID after that shouldn't matter since A doesn't need to really use the PID for anything, right?

Comment: @mosvy @ikkachu Now I think I understand your point @mosvy. But this detail seems largely irrelevant in practice, since the point is that once waitpid() returns the caller knows that the child no longer exists, and it should not try to interact with that PID. The only place where things might be complicated, AFAICS, is in multithreaded programs: there would be a potential for a race in multithreaded programs where other threads interacted with the PID at the same time as one thread did a waitpid(). But in a single-threaded program, I see no unsafety in `pid = waitpid(-1, &s, 0)`.

Comment: @mtk, with a multithreaded program, you might have even have another thread of the same program create a new child with the very same PID before the thread calling `waitpid()` has finished with any bookkeeping there is to do. That might cause problems too. I think I've heard it's not a good idea to launch children from multiple threads, I don't know if this is the (only) reason.

Comment: I also don't know what practical scenario @mosvy had in mind, as they didn't appear to mention any.

Comment: @ilkkachu thread ids and process ids live in the same namespace, At least in Linux. But, yes, it's probably a good idea to not create children in the first place, I will not argue against that, LOL. As to practical scenarios, ANY scenario where you want to do ANYTHING with the PID returned by waipid() other than check if it's != -1 is problematical.

Comment: @mosvy, so, I think the scenario we've were discussing above, was where a process launches (say) two child processes, then afterwards calls `wait*()` and uses the returned PID to find out which one of the two children finished. Can you be specific about what issues PID reuse can cause in that scenario?

Answer (score 8):

Bernstein doesn't give much context for this "Right Thing" remark, but I'll hazard a guess: having fork(2) return a PID is inconsistent with open(2), creat(2) etc returning file descriptors. The rest of the Unix system could have done process manipulation with a file descriptor representing a process, instead of a PID. A system call [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) exists, which allows a somewhat better interaction between signals and file descriptors, and shows that a file-descriptor-representing a process could work out.

Comment: signalfd(2) looks awesome, thanks for mentioning it! Too bad it's Linux-only.

Comment: There have been discussions about `pidfd_open` as well in Linux, see for example https://lwn.net/Articles/789023/

Answer (score 8):

It's just a musing on the lines of "it would be great if Unix was designed differently than it is".

The problem with PIDs is that they live in a global namespace where they could be reused for another process, and it would be nice if `fork()` returned in the parent some kind of handle that would be guaranteed to always refer to the child process, and that it could pass to other processes via inheritance or unix sockets / `SCM_RIGHTS`[1].

See also the discussion [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/784831/) for a recent effort to "fix" that in Linux, including adding a flag to `clone()` which will cause it to return a pid-fd instead of a PID.

But even then, that would not eliminate the need for that self-pipe hack [2] or better interfaces, since the signals notifying a parent process about the state of a child are not the only ones you would like to handle in the main loop of the program. Unfortunately, things like `epoll(7) + signalfd(2)` on Linux or `kqueue(2)` on BSD are not standard -- the only *standard* interface (but not supported on older systems) is the much inferior `pselect(2)`.

[1] Preventing the PID from being re-cycled by the time the `waitpid()` syscall had returned and its return value was used could probably be achieved on newer systems by using `waitid(.., WNOWAIT)` instead.

[2] I would not comment on D.J. Bernstein claim that he invented it (sorry for the apophasis ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

The point is that there are many programs that operate an event-loop style model based around monitoring file descriptors with [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)/[poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)/[epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html). But there were various events that historically didn't notify using file descriptors--among them process state transition (e.g., termination) of a child process. The need to separately handle these other events (which include timer expirations, signals, and synchronization events such as semaphore changes) complicated programming of the event-loop model.

In the last several years, Linux development has been chipping away at this problem, so that nowadays we have [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) (make signals readable from a file descriptor), [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) (a synchronization primitive whose handle is a file descriptor), and [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) (create timers that notify via a file descriptor), all of which produce file descriptors that can be fed to [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)/[poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)/[epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html).

And finally, recent versions of Linux have added the concept of a handle for a process as a file descriptor. The `CLONE_PIDFD` flag of [clone3()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone3.2.html) can be used to create a child process for which a file descriptor as handle is returned. The file descriptor can likewise be fed to [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)/[poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)/[epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) and indicates as readable if the the child process terminates.

Comment: Compare FreeBSD's `pdfork()` introduced in version 9.