# Are socketpairs useable as signal-safe buffers?

Tags: signals, posix, socket, unix-sockets

I am thinking on a way of communication between signal handlers and the main program. Note, I use mosly non-blocking signals (a new signal can arrive even while a signal handler is executed), so I am looking for a lock-free solution.

My current idea is this:

1. Creating a `socketpair(...)` yet before the signal handler is installed (with `sigaction(...)`).
2. The signal handler sends everything what I need to do, into a file descriptor of this socketpair.
3. The main process polls the incoming data from the other file descriptor, and processes is as it is needed.

Of course I plan to set up a quite high internal buffer size (with `setSockOptInt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, size);`), and correctly terminate the program on an overflow (`send(...)` in the signal handler returns some... unfeasible.

I think, possibly it might violate some Posix.* standards, because they restrict the signal-safe libc functions quite strongly. However, writing into sockets is, as far I know atomic (I am nearly 100% sure that it is the case if I use `send()` to datagram sockets).

Is it correct? Could it work?

Comment: See `man 7 signal-safety`; `send` is signal-safe. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: Are you messages fixed-sized? If so, you could also consider using a pipe.

Comment: @AndyDalton Thanks! It helps a lot.

Comment: @AndyDalton Yes, that would match better, but a pipe is not a socket. `setSockOptInt()` probably would not work on a pipe. And i need to set a *big* internal buffer (to minimize the chance of problems caused by bursting signals).

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531171/5132 and anything else mentioning the "self-pipe trick".

Answer (score 1):

For a list of the functions that are safe in signal context, take a look at `man 7 signal-safety`.  From that page:

> ```
> The  set  of  functions  required to be async-signal-safe by POSIX.1 is
> shown in the following table.  The functions not otherwise  noted  were
> required  to  be  async-signal-safe  in POSIX.1-2001; the table details
> changes in the subsequent standards.
>
> Function               Notes
> ...
> send(2)
> sendmsg(2)
> sendto(2)
> ...
> write(2)
> ```

So, using `send()` or `write()` on the file descriptor associated with your socket (or any file descriptor for that matter) is signal-safe.

Comment: I'd also recommend setting the file descriptor to non-blocking in order to eliminate the possibility of a deadlocked process.